# How to remove all hidden elements?

Tags: c#, html, css, html-agility-pack

I am looking for a way to strip out all elements in the HTML doc that are hidden.

I am able to remove elements that contain style `display:none` or `visible:hidden` but what about those that are hidden because of their CSS class?  Is there a way to look at say a `DIV` with class "item-description" and know that the stylesheet for this class contains `display:none`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing this with HtmlAgilityPack since it doesn't take into account the styles, only the DOM.

If you want to really be able to handle the styles after having loaded your html you must

- parse the css (following all `@imports` and other tricks)
- apply each rules to each DOM node by using the selectors
- apply the inheritance rules to see what is hidden or not depending on the parent hierarchy and rules
- resolve consistency problems (what if a component is visible but not its parent? How would that translate into your final document?)
- I hope you decided on the browser you want to emulate, since some css rules will apply to specific browsers.
- I also hope you don't have javascript that touches the DOM on the page...

I'm sure I'm forgetting some more things... Don't go there! There are grues!

If you really want to get this result in C#, perhaps embedding a rendering engine and then querying it through javascript would be a better way to do it.